# JPA Query with boolean check with one parent multiple child values

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa

I have below sample JPA query

```
@Query("select u from User u WHERE (u.isExist = ?1 OR ?1 IS NULL) ")
Page<User> getUsersWithParams(Boolean isExist);
```

I have `User` table and child table `User_Address`. One `User` can have multiple `User_Address`

In `User_Address` I have field called `isDefaultAddress` boolean true/false.

So if one of the address is set to `true`, then I need to show data otherwise not.

```
User
1 

User_Address
id  user_id  isDefaultAddress 
1   1          true
2   1          false
3   1          false
```

How to manage this via JPA query with pagination?

Comment: Can you provide entity classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can you JAP repository method don't need write query. It will retrieve all User with all address.

```
Page<User> findByUserAddressIsDefaultAddressTrue(Pageable 
page);
```

For Above User and UserAddress entity should be like below.

```
Public class User {

private List<UserAddress> UserAddress;

}

public class UserAddress {

private boolean isDefaultAddress;
}
```

Comment: @Jacksan got your answer?